# How to create a C++ array with variable elements?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double dx2(int t, int x, int dx)
{
    return (-9.8*cos(x));
}

int square(int x) 
{
    return (x*x);
}

double RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h)
{
    double k1, k2, k3, k4, l1, l2, l3, l4, diff1, diff2;
    k1 = h*dx2(t,x,dx);
    l1 = h*k1;
    k2 = h*dx2(t+h/2,x+l1/2,dx+k1/2);
    l2 = h*k2;
    k3 = h*dx2(t+h/2,x+l2/2,dx+k2/2);
    l3 = h*k3;
    k4 = h*dx2(t+h,x+l3,dx+k3);
    l4 = h*k4;
    diff1 = (l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)/float(6);
    diff2 = (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/float(6);
    double OUT[] = {diff1, diff2};
    return OUT;
}

int main()
{
    double diff, t, t0, t1, x, x0, dx, dx0, h, N;
    N = 1000;
    t0 = 0;
    t  = t0;
    t1 = 10;
    x0 = 0;
    x  = x0;
    dx0 = 0;
    dx  = dx0;
    h = (t1 - t0) / float(N);

    for(int i = 1; i<=N; i++) {
        diff = RK4(t,x,dx,h);
        x = x + diff;
        t = t + h;
    }
    cout << diff;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see in this program I am solving the 2nd-order differential equation (if there is a way to insert LaTeX equations into my question please tell me):

d2x/dt2= -9.8 cos(x)

which is an example of the simple pendulum's equations of motion. The problem lines are 33 and 34. In it I am attempting to define the first element of the OUT array as diff1 and the second element as diff2. Whenever I compile this program (named `example.cpp`) I get the error:

```
g++ -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" (in directory: /home/fusion809/Documents/CodeLite/firstExample)
example.cpp: In function ‘double RK4(float, float, float, float)’:
example.cpp:33:9: error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘double’ in return
  return OUT;
         ^~~
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Can you create an array of `enum`?

Comment: Whoever downvotes questions like this, please be so kind as to leave a note why. Thank you. To me, it sounds alright, even though it's asking what might look obvious to an experienced C++ programmer. Remember that science people don't necessarily know programming languages.

Comment: Well, most code seems to be irrelevant to the problem, whatever that is. That, combined with the title, makes it unclear what the question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly, since you're returning an array of `double`'s, that decays to `double*`, but the function is defined to return `double`. An array of type `T` and the type `T` are different types in C++, and they can't be converted between, generally speaking.

In this case, you might be better off with a `std::pair<T1, T2>` (`#include <utility>`) since you're using C++ and the standard library, or a structure with two fields of type `double`. Look up `std::pair<>` and `std::tie<>`, the former being used to make pairs of elements of different types, and the latter being used to make tuples of different types of arbitrary size.

When you write the `std::pair`'s elements to `std::cout`, use the `first`, `second` members to access the pair's fields. A `std::pair` can't be directly output using the overloaded stream operator for `std::cout`.

**Edit:**

```
#include <utility>

std::pair<double, double> RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h)
{
    /* snip */
    diff1 = (l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)/float(6);
    diff2 = (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/float(6);
    return {diff1, diff2};
}

int main()
{
    double x, dx;
    /* snip */
    for(int i = 1; i<=N; i++) {
        std::pair<double, double> diff = RK4(t,x,dx,h);
        // or use with C++11 and above for brevity
        auto diff = RK4(t,x,dx,h);
        x = x + diff.first;
        dx = dx + diff.second;
        t = t + h;
    }
    cout << x << " " << dx << "\n" ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `first` and `second` are public data members, not functions.

Comment: Sorry, I keep confusing that. Thank you for the note.

Comment: OK. I'm trying to follow what you mean, it's just I'm trying to keep in mind exactly what this means I need to do to my code... Your answer seems too theoretical rather than applied, could you per chance show me how it should be implemented with my previous example?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by adding an array of two doubles to the `diff` variable of type `double` in `main()`? Adding an array to a scalar variable makes little sense. This information is required for me to provide a definition of `main()`, as currently I can't seem to figure out what is being added to `diff`.

Comment: You mean the `x=x+diff`? Well I probably should rewrite it to `x=x+diff[1]` and `dx=dx+diff[2]`. I just do not know how to add the first element of diff to the scalar, x, and the second element of diff to dx.

Comment: Here's a gist showing what I mean and what I managed to get so far myself (although it is still returning errors) https://gist.github.com/49a3f1363d6837ea87eec8d5dac0bcc6. Here's the exact error message if it helps https://gist.github.com/fusion809/78a4edebbb684f56686393e3df7a8868.

Comment: Thanks, but still running into issues here is the code I created using your latest edit https://gist.github.com/2f4f3ec21237ca2d5d4c702837180887. My compiler is giving the error message: https://gist.github.com/fusion809/b401ffe6b2e84ea506bdb11784f0e447.

Comment: Oops, I found an error I mistook an "or" in your comments for "and". It's working now. Thanks a million!

Comment: Use only one of the two lines I've separated by the comment. They have identical meaning, but differ in appearance.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of your `RK4` function is `double`, which is a single value, but you're trying to return an array of two of them.  That won't work.  You could change the return type to `double*` and use `new double[2]` to allocate an array, but it'd be simpler and safer to use `std::pair<double, double>` as the return type.  Then you can just do `return { diff1, diff2 };`.

Comment: Changing 33 / 34 to `return { diff1, diff2 };` gives: `g++ -Wall -o "example" "example.cpp" (in directory: /home/fusion809/Documents/CodeLite/firstExample)
example.cpp: In function ‘double RK4(float, float, float, float)’:
example.cpp:32:24: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘double’ in return
  return { diff1, diff2 };
                        ^
Compilation failed.
`

Comment: You need to first change the return type to `std::pair<double, double>`.

Comment: How? I am new to C++, sorry if what I am asking seems trivial to you, I'm just trying my best to pick up this language.

Comment: Just change the `double RK4` to `std::pair<double, double> RK4` at the top of the function.  That's the part that says what type of data the function returns.

Comment: See this answer or my answer below. What exactly can't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

To return several values from function you have several choice:

- as all you returned type are identical, you may return array:

  ```
  std::array<double, 2> RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h)
  {
      // ...
      return {{diff1, diff2}};
  }
  ```

  or `std::vector`

  ```
  std::vector<double> RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h)
  {
      // ...
      return {{diff1, diff2}};
  }
  ```
- You may return `std::tuple` or `std::pair` (limited to 2 elements):

  ```
  std::pair<double, double> RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h)
  {
      // ...
      return {{diff1, diff2}};
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  std::tuple<double, double> RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h)
  {
      // ...
      return {{diff1, diff2}};
  }
  ```
- You may also create a custom class

  ```
  struct RK4Result
  {
      double diff1;
      double diff2;
  };

  RK4Result RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h)
  {
      // ...
      return {diff1, diff2};
  }
  ```
- And for type expensive to move, you may use any previous method, but by **out** parameters:

  ```
  struct RK4Result
  {
      double diff1;
      double diff2;
  };

  void RK4(float t, float x, float dx, float h, RK4Result& res)
  {
      // ...
      res = {diff1, diff2};
  }
  ```